# Next.js project error in production build

Tags: next.js, production-environment, production

I'm builded project with custom server, and starting with `next start`

If `NODE_ENV = 'production'` throws an error as on screen

If `NODE_ENV != 'production'` it works properly, but in dev environment

package.json:

```html
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "next lint",
    "build:next": "next build",
    "build:server": "tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "build": "npm run build:next && npm run build:server",
    "dev": "node server/index.js",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production & node dist/server/index.js"
  },
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, anything text-based should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can't.

Please see the document around [Error Handling (for App Dir)](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling) or [Error Handling (for Pages dir)](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/error-handling).

Both the Client Component and Server Component can use these (Error Boundary) to show error.

For example (`error.tsx`):

```js
"use client";

type Props = {
  error: Error;
  reset: () => void;
};

export default function ErrorPage({ error, reset }: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Error</h1>
      <div>{error.message}</div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => reset()}>
        Retry
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to catch all errors of the project, just place this file as `app/error.tsx`